# Invalid instruction operand: sub edx, bl

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

```
.data
VarA byte 132d
VarB byte 01101001b
VarC dword 0af5h
VarD byte 85d

.code
mov al, varA
mov ah, varB
sub al, ah
call DumpRegs
mov edx, varC
mov bl, varD
sub edx, bl
call DumpRegs
add eax, ebx
call DumpRegs
```

I don't really know why I'm having this issue. the `sub edx, bl` is where the invalid instruction operand is located.

I tried an ptrd dword offset but didn't work.

Comment: You need to zero-extend or sign-extend `varD` into a 32-bit register.  Like with `movzx ebx, byte ptr [varD]`

Comment: Processors don't have mixed size addition/subtraction (e.g. add 8-bit register to 32-bit register), so convert the smaller to the larger size and use the larger size for the subtraction.  As Peter says, there's two possible conversions, and the right one depends on whether the byte data is signed or unsigned.